# Finding an example a pair of sequences converging to 0 but such that their quotient diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I was tasked with finding an example for a pair of sequences $  (a_{n})_{n=1}^\infty$ , $  (b_{n})_{n=1}^\infty$, such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}= 0$, and at the same time $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}$$

doesn't exist.

In this context, I don't really understand what does ''Not existing'' mean....does it mean the limit goes to ${\infty}$ ? Or rather does it have something to do with partial sums of sub-sequences, such as some $2n$ and $2n-1$ whose limit of a ratio must not exist?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to replace "series" by "sequence" (a series is a summation, and there is no summation here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take $a_n = 1/n$, and $b_n = 1/n^2$. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} n,$$
which does not exist.

As for your second question, not existing means that the ratio $a_n/b_n$ does not converge towards a real value. This happens e.g. if the sequence tends to infinity, or if it fluctuates between separate values.

Comment: is it in any way related to partial sums (as in sub-sequences)?

Comment: @Bak1139, yeah. If two subsequences have different limits, the sequence will not converge. For instance, the sequence $(-1)^n$ has two subsequences $1, 1, 1, \ldots$ and $-1, -1, -1, \ldots$, which have different limits. But it can of course also happen that all or some subsequences tend to infinity, in which case we also do not have convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n= 1/n$ and $b_n= (-1)^n 1/n$.

Comment: $(-1)^\infty$ is defined?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } (-1)^n
\end{eqnarray*}
does not converge.

Comment: got it, nice idea